# Why aren't these propel many-to-many relationships working?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, propel

I am following this documentation: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/04-relationships.html#manytomany_relationships

I have a very similar set up (albeit a little simplified for readability):

**Logbook**

```
  <table name="logbook" phpName="Logbook" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" size="10" sqlType="int(10) unsigned" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="location" phpName="Location" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="false"/>
  </table>
```

**Contact**

```
  <table name="contact" phpName="Contact" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" size="10" sqlType="int(10) unsigned" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="title" phpName="Title" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true"/>
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true"/>
    <column name="telephone" phpName="Telephone" type="VARCHAR" size="20" required="true"/>
  </table>
```

**Logbook Contact**

```
  <table name="logbook_contact" phpName="LogbookContact" idMethod="native" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="logbook_id" phpName="LogbookId" type="INTEGER" size="10" sqlType="int(10) unsigned" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="contact_id" phpName="ContactId" type="INTEGER" size="10" sqlType="int(10) unsigned" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="contact" name="fk_logbook_contact_contact" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
      <reference local="contact_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="logbook" name="fk_logbook_contact_logbook" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
      <reference local="logbook_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <index name="fk_logbook_contact_contact">
      <index-column name="contact_id"/>
    </index>
  </table>
```

Notice the `isCrossRef="true"` on the logbook_contact table, which shows this is a junction table. From here I have re-run `propel-gen om` and even `propel-gen convert-conf` (after clearing out the build directory) but I still don't seem to be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
/* presume $logbook has been LogbookQuery::create()'d already... */
$contacts = $logbook->getContacts();
$nbContacts = $logbook->countContacts();
```

I use Zend Studio, and I don't see it in the code-hint window:

[image: No $logbook->getContacts();]

Can anyone suggest to me what I might have done wrong here? I'm happy for you to point me to docs - I have followed these as closely as possible and everything up until `$test` works just fine.

Comment: Which Propel version do you use? Did you check the generated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call `getContacts()` on a `Logbook` instance, not on a `PropelCollection`. See your code, it seems you fetch a collection of `Logbook` instead of an instance:

```
$this->logbook = $this->company->getLogbooks();
```

Here, `$this->logbook` seems to be a `PropelCollection` regarding the autocompletion output. It's not a `Logbook` object. You can try:

```
$test = $this->logbook[0]->getContacts();
```

Comment: Great - thanks! I found that I can use findOne() to get one object instead of a collection, but when using relations like this, can I get just one also? i.e an alternative to getContacts, like getOneContact()?

Comment: Yes. And if you filter on the primary key, use findPk() instead of findOneById() :)

Comment: Yeah I've been using that too :) So what's the best alternative to getLogbooks() here to get just one record, using the relation still?

Comment: @LeonardChallis, you won't be able to get one object on a many-to-many relationship, but you can loop through the collection from `->getContacts()`, or access it directly through an array substring